# Audit.Net Audit.MVC Extension Is Not Logging

Tags: asp.net-mvc, audit.net

I'm trying to setup Audit.NET's Audit.MVC extension, but it's not creating log files. I'm thinking im missing something obvious here, here's what i've got, i can't find any more documentation on what i should be doing.

Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using EE.Controllers;
using EE.CustomFilters;
using EE.DAL;
using EE.Models;
using EE.ViewModels;
using EE.ViewModels.AdminViewModels;

namespace EE.Controllers
{

public class AdminController : BaseController
{
  [Audit] 
  public ActionResult Index()
  { 
   //do stuff
  }
}
```

Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
  //other stuff

  Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup()
               .UseFileLogProvider(_ => _
                   .Directory(@"C:\Logs"));
}
```

(or Startup.cs i've tried both)

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
      Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup()
           .UseFileLogProvider(_ => _
               .Directory(@"C:\Logs"));
}
```

Is there anything else i need to do? Any ideas?

Comment: Which framework version do you target? From which class your Controller is inheriting?

Comment: @thepirat000 .Net 4.7.1, the controller inherits from a base controller, i've edited the OP

Comment: And I guess your `BaseController` inherits from `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`. If that's the case, everything looks fine. You can open a new issue [here](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/issues/new/choose)

Comment: @thepirat000 Yeah it does, just want to make sure i'm trying to set this up in the right way before i open an issue. Please see the edits above.

Comment: Do you hit the `Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup()` call if you put a breakpoint there?

Comment: No, i was unsure if it was supposed to be hit (im still learning a lot of this)

Comment: Yes, the `Setup()` needs to run before any action. `Application_Start` should be fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182556/discussion-between-thepirat000-and-loveforfire33).